# TextMesh pro Unity: text not rendering via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

on a buttons onClick function script method is called and new empty gameObjects are created and added a textMeshPro object. Appearing in hierarchy but its not appearing in gameView.

here's the simple code is testing with start thread:

```
 [SerializeField]
public TextMeshPro text;

[SerializeField]
public GameObject g;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //test1
    GameObject ga = new GameObject();
    ga.transform.SetParent(g.transform, false);


    //test2

    //text = g.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    text = ga.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    text.text = "Cool ... ";
    text.fontSize = 36;

    //test3 __________________
    //font is added by default.
    //text.font = Resources.Load("fonts/Arial",) as Font;
    //text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();


}
```

How will my code render textMeshPro text?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the game, switching to Scene-view in runtime, and then doubleclick your newly-created object in hierarchy. Your code is definitely working, I just suspect that new object is out of the camera view. It should appear at "g" position.

Comment: Yes, I saw the text object in the scene view. How can I set it in cameraView? I tried manually adjusting position though.

Comment: Just check that your in-game camera is looking at it. And also that object's Z position is not the same as camera's. Just use object's transform like usual.